# Linux: Install Skype 4.0 but keep 2.2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype

[Skype 4.0 for Linux has been released.](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTExOTk) I would like to test the new version but keep the old 2.2 around just in case. I cannot find the 2.2 installation .deb, even though I thought that I did save one (I usually do save installation files).

**EDIT:** Is there any way to "export" a .deb package from the currently-installed Skype?

Comment: If you're just looking for a copy of the 2.2 deb I have that.  But I have no way to prove that it's the legit version.  sha1sum of the 64-bit deb is `171e50e1e25cf844ff5cdf9ee66da91b0b440634  skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: Yes, I am wary but if you could somehow make that .deb available to the Gmail user with my SO username I would be grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's completely unnecessary to run a virtual machine or a chroot just for skype.

if you download the statically linked (not requiring system dependancies) skype distributable, you can run both Skype 4.0 and Skype 2.2 on the same system.

install skype 4.0 using the deb, and download the statically linked version of skype 2.2 and extract it to `/opt` and then add `/opt/skype-VERSION` to your `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc`

rename the `skype` executable in `/opt/skype-VERSION` to something like `skype-2.2`

and once you've done all of that, you should be able to run `skype-2.2` and `skype` for either version.

here's Skype 2.2 static: http://download.skype.com/linux/skype_static-2.2.0.35.tar.bz2

Comment: Thank you. How did you find that link?

Comment: Archlinux versions their package sources, so when I need a link to an old packge, I just look at an older version of the PKGBUILD, and the URL is right there.

Comment: @dotancohen I'm not very sure I recall how I found that link. I believe I used my Google-fu to find it.

Comment: After four months? I don't even recall what I ate four hours ago! It wasn't critical though, I see that your google-fu is more powerful than my own!

Comment: The statically typed version still required a lot of local dependencies for me. I went with the dynamically linked version, as it also provides a huge benefit: DBUS remote API, which is used by some plugins like e.g. bitlbee-skype.

Answer (score 3):

They are still downloadable, the download page on [skype.com](http://skype.com) just points to the 4.0 .deb file(s):

- [Here is the i386 2.2](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb).
- [And here the amd64 2.2](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_amd64.deb).

Comment: Note for 64-bit users (amd64). After downloading the files from mclemme you must also install dependencies. The libc6-i386 written in the .deb file seems to be incorrect! At least it doesn't fit on new systems (>= ubuntu maverick)
You should use libc6-dev-amd64 instead. Total list of packages:
ia32-libs
lib32asound2
lib32gcc1
lib32stdc++6
libc6-dev-amd64

Answer (score 3):

Answer by spyroboy is great, but in general there may be incompatibilities between the way versions store user information (e.g. chat history, etc.). This is in ~/.Skype . The release notes  make reference to upgrading the way this information is stored. So, I haven't tried spyroboy's solution, but suggest making a copy of the .Skype directory before running 4.0 for the first time if you hope to keep chat history, etc. available for version 2.2

Comment: This is a very good point.

Comment: it's not like this is relevant to the question however there is a concern regarding the nature of the question. it is a good point but there's no solution around it. it's inherent to running multiple versions of any software. I believe worrying about this is a lot less critical than running a whole chroot or virtual machine for a voip application.

alternatively, I doubt anyone really wants to do this except me, you can open the Skype binary in a hex editor and probably change the configuration directory to something else. although sounds blackhat-ish, it's more than likely perfectly safe.

Answer (score 2):

Try virtualbox. Install the new version in a VM.

As for the searching of the lost file, enter the command in a shell: 
 `locate *Skype*.deb`
or
`locate *skype*.deb`

Comment: Thanks. I did use locate and found that I have an _old_ 2.0 Skype version in my backups.

Answer (score 2):

You could either install a virtual machine running another instance of your preferred derivative of Linux or look at `chroot`. [Here](http://jblevins.org/log/ubuntu-chroot) is a great guide to get started.

Comment: Thank you, chroot does seem to be the right way to do what I am trying to do.